# Unable to access CouchDB remotely

Tags: azure, couchdb

I'm Unable to access CouchDB remotely. I'm using a Windows 2008 virtual machine in Azure.

I did the following,

1) Installed IIS on windows server 2008.

2) Created an endpoint for port 5984

3) Installed CouchDB & verified the same by using futon

```
 http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils
```

4) Created a subdomain ( db.mydomainxyz.com ) with my domain registrar & verified. If I type http://db.mydomainxyz.com/ in browser - IIS7 default page gets displayed.

5) Made couchdb to listen on all network adapters by setting => bind_address = 0.0.0.0

6) Created vhosts to point to my domain = > db.mydomainxyz.com:5984 = /db/_rewrite/

After doing all these things I'm still unable to access CouchDB remotely http://db.mydomainxyz.com:5984/

Is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: Is IIS listening to 5984 port?

Comment: @Aurélien, 
I didn't do any specific settings in IIS. Anyway how do I find if IIS listens on port 5984?

Comment: @Aurélien - only CouchDB ( erl.exe ) is listening on port 5984

Comment: The last part of the question got me confused. If you wanted to connect to port 5984 you didn't need to setup IIS as a reverse proxy.

Comment: If you're not very familiar with reverse proxy management, you should first try [CouchDB's embedded virtual hosts management](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Virtual_Hosts).

Comment: I didn't setup anything related / specific to CouchDB in IIS. At the moment I want to access couchDB through its default port 5984.

Comment: As a side note,  I'm afraid your question is off-topic. StackOverflow is about programming. If you have system administration questions, the way to go is ServerFault.

Comment: Is there a firewall at play?

Comment: @JanLehnardt I use windows azure virtual machine. A firewall should be there as part of Azure. But it should not create problem as I have created an endpoint for port 5984.

Comment: @JanLehnardt I thought just creating an endpoint in Azure portal is enough. After banging my head for a while, I made windows firewall to allow couchdb's erl.exe file. After this I'm able to access couchdb remotely. Kindly create an answer I will accept the same.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the `bind_address`, CouchDB must be restarted. The problem is that its daemon is very resilient. So even if you tried to restart it, it probably never stopped. Restart your  virtual machine instead.

See the [similar discussion on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/79453/why-cant-i-access-my-couchdb-instance-externally-on-ubuntu-9-04-server) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have restarted the virtual machine few times. Still I'm unable to connect. Right now I get error " Host not found .." previously it was " Google chrome could not connect to ..."

Comment: If you change `bind_address` in Futon, the admin UI, CouchDB does the restart for you.

Answer (score 0):

This command solves the issue:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Apache CouchDB" dir=in action=allow service=any enable=yes profile=any localport=5984 protocol=tcp
```